# D&D 3.5 equivalent of PF 1.0 Persistent Spell Metamagic

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic

Does Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 have any equivalent (or at least alternative way to get the same feature) of Metamagic Feat "Persistent Spell" from Pathfinder 1.0?

DISCLAIMER: Contrary to common naming between the two, Persistent Spell in D&D 3.5 (24 hour spell duration) is entirely different thing than Persistent Spell in PF 1.0 (roll twice for Save, take loosing result if there is one).

https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Persistent%20Spell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I am rather confident that 3.5e does not have any equivalent of this effect. Rerolls are rare in 3.5e, and offensive ones are even rarer.

The closest 3.5e comes to this would be Twin Spell (*Tome and Blood*, *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, *Complete Arcane*, *Player’s Guide to Faerûn*), but that doesn’t *just* have them save twice—it applies the entire spell twice. It also increases the spell’s level by 4, twice that of the PF Persistent Spell.

Repeat Spell (*Tome and Blood*, *Deities and Demigods*, *Complete Arcane*, [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#repeatSpell)) is kind of like Twin Spell, only delayed by a round. Not much savings, though, since it increases a spell’s level by 3.

Comment: Does this Twin Spell have respective metamagic rod? Also: how does one pump success rate of spells in 3.5 without such reroll? In PF 1.0 I remember using a combo of Witch Hex + Spell cast with Persistent Metamagic rod = "Save or Die" Spell becomes "Just Die" Spell.

Comment: @NecXelos I don’t believe it does, and a quick search doesn’t find any. Ditto for the Repeat Spell I just added to my answer. Anyway, for “just die” one usually avoids a save altogether (e.g. buffing, summoning, *enervation*, a mailman build), but otherwise save-or-X spells are usually rather reliable due to SAD and the ability to target a foe’s weak saves. Steps beyond that are too large for a comment, though of course there are more. It’s usually just easier to not bother and skip saves if you’re worried about the target making them.

Comment: For the record, I don't find any feats that appear to repeat the save if it's *successful*, either.

Comment: Does either Twin or Repeat have a dedicated Metamagic Rod in any splatbook?

Comment: @NecXelos You already asked, and I already answered, that question—no, neither does, at least as far as I know/could find, or anyone else I saw discussing it on the internet knew/could find. It’s not outrageous to assume they’d cost the same as other +3 spell level and +4 spell level rods, but I’m not 100% sure they’re entirely consistent, and in any event that’s certainly not RAW, so check with your DM.